# Как удаленно получить инфу о доменной машине?

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory

подскажите пожалуйста есть ли в C# возможность находясь в учетке обычного доменного пользователя получить информацию об установленном ПО и информацию о железе на другой доменной машине?

Comment: а у обычного доменного пользователя есть на это права?

Comment: Теоретически можно. Смотреть WMI. Если WMI с вашими правами пустит и машина включена - то получите. Средствами AD вы такую информацию не получите. На счёт альтернативы WMI - не подскажу.

Comment: @nick_n_a, так то для WMI нужно обладать специфическими правами...

Comment: Что б не писать кучу кода для WMI, можете открыть "Управление компьютером" (или аналогичную другую оснастку, найти в дебрях Панель управления), нажать меню действие (action) - подключится к удаленному компьютеру. Если получится - то можно пробовать через WMI. Для доступа WMI учетная запись программы должна иметь достаточно прав доступа.

Comment: Еще можно попробовать через OpenRemoteBaseKey. Читаем реестр удаленного ПК и получаем список софта. Правда, и в этом случае могут потребоваться спец. права.

Comment: А да, я недочитал "Обычный доменный пользователь", да... это изюминка вопроса.

Comment: Ещё есть длинный не очень хороший путь - через RDP + RDP скрипт (тоже права нужны). Если есть у юзверя права по RDP шастать - то можно.

Comment: А как вы предполагаете это сделать? Путей немного, но нужно определится с одним из (плюс наличие доступа). Или получить доступ через один из извесных интерфейсов (RDP, remote file (SAMBA), remote registry, WMI), или... писать клиента и закидывать на машины что б собрать инфу.

Comment: рассматриваю разные варианты в поисках самого простого и быстро реализуемого

Comment: А с какой целью обычному пользователю может потребоваться знать железо и софт другой машины?

Comment: попробуйте поискать [здесь](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На тех машинах, к которым вы хотите осуществлять удаленный доступ, необходимо:

- убедиться, что включена служба удаленного реестра
- добавить в список разрешений ключа реестра `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurePipeServers\winreg` группу "Пользователи домена", и установить галку "Разрешить" напротив пункта "Чтение".

После этого, вы можете получить доступ к любой информации из реестра удаленной машины из-под любой учетной записи домена. Например, список программ, установленных глобально (для всех пользователей компьютера) можно вывести так:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{    
    class Program
    {  
        public static void Main(string[] argv)
        {
            RegistryKey remote = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "\\\\compname");
            using (remote)
            {
                RegistryKey subkeyUninstall = remote.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall");
                using (subkeyUninstall)
                {
                    foreach (var subkey_name in subkeyUninstall.GetSubKeyNames())
                    {
                        RegistryKey subkeyApp = subkeyUninstall.OpenSubKey(subkey_name);
                        using (subkeyApp)
                        {
                            object dispname = subkeyApp.GetValue("DisplayName");
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dispname as string)) Console.WriteLine(dispname as string);
                            else Console.WriteLine(subkey_name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }    
    }    
}
```

Безопасность такого решения, впрочем, под серьезным вопросом, так как доступ придется открывать ко всему реестру. Существует групповая политика для разрешения доступа на уровне отдельных ключей, но она, насколько я понял, не позволяет дать доступ только на чтение, так что это еще хуже.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

1. Пишем программу, которая ходит по компьютерам в сети и через WMI,
   либо реестр и собирает информацию о машинах и записывает в
   какой-нибудь txt-файл. 1 машина-1 файл.
2. На какой-нибудь 1 машине настраиваем планировщик задач, что бы он запускал программу из под высокопревелигированной учетки и время от времени перезаписывал(актуализировал) данные.

В итоге получается, что программа запускается по расписанию и кладет данные на общую шару и любой пользователь обладающий доступ на чтение, может открыть необходимый TXT и увидеть нужную информацию.

И проблем с безопасностью никаких не будет.

Ну это самый простой вариант. Решение "по взрослому"- это написать сервис к которому будут обращаться пользователи. А сам сервис будет иметь админские права и делать то, что я описал в первых пунктах.